# material-ui-search-bar as Styled Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I was using [material-ui-search-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-search-bar) like this and it worked fine:

```
<SearchBar
         style={{
          margin: '0 auto',
          maxWidth: 800,
        }}
        />
```

However, when I change it to styled components, the styling doesn't work properly and the search bar extends to the whole screen.

```
export const StyledSearchBar = styled(SearchBar)`
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800;
`;
```

I also tried using `maxWidth`. How can I fix this?

I am unable to create a sandbox due to MUI theme errors.

Comment: Please add a working example using https://codesandbox.io

Comment: I tried but couldn't create one. I don't get the error - the code is pretty straightforward @Dekel https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-williams-24en2?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Are you referring to material-ui-search-bar library? Is there no way to use it in codesandbox? @keikai

Comment: Yes, I am already using it. The seachbar works fine. But if I try to move the inline styling into styled components styling, that part doesn't work properly. @keikai

Comment: @keikai check my answer, it explains everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`material-ui-search-bar` requires `material-ui` version 1.0 or above.
You need the following dependencies for your code to work:

```
"@material-ui/core": "4.9.11",
"@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
"material-ui": "1.0.0-beta.47",
"material-ui-search-bar": "1.0.0-beta.14",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-scripts": "3.3.0",
"styled-components": "5.1.0"
```

Regarding the width - node that with styled component you neet to set the px on the width:

```
export const StyledSearchBar = styled(SearchBar)`
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
`;
```

And here is the updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-material-ui-search-box-example-4mpoc

Comment: It was the missing px!

Comment: Indeed. And now you understand how important it is to create a working example. I spent much more time on fixing your codesandbox than to find the issue with the missing px :)

Comment: @Dekel Nice work. By the way, do you think this version problem worth an issue?

Comment: The `material-ui` component (the old one) is deprecated, and this also means that the `material-ui-search-bar` is probably also not really maintained (last published 2 years ago). I think it's much better to use up-to-date packages. If it was my decision - I would drop the usage of `material-ui-search-bar` and use the components provided by material-ui/core

Comment: what alternatives do I have for a search bar? I couldn't find anything relevant in /core

Comment: I'm not sure what is your requirement from the search-bar, but it looks just like a standard Autocomplete component that you have in material-ui/lab